# Not able to write logs using log4j2

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, logging, log4j2

I am using the following configuration for log4j2.xml with spring boot for logging in apache tomcat logs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="60">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="logdir">${sys:catalina.base}/logs</Property>
        <Property name="layout">%d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${layout}"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="FILEAPPENDER"
                     fileName="${logdir}/doc-reader.log"
                     filePattern="${logdir}/doc-reader.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${layout}"/>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 KB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="4"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="FILEAPPENDER"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="com.mypackage"
                level="info"
                additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="FILEAPPENDER"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This configuration is able to create both logs and compressed logs in the logs/ folder of tomcat. And it also writes system generated messages like:

```
2018-12-11 11:16:20,359 [http-nio-8089-exec-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet- Completed initialization in 9 ms
```

But when I try to do logging using my controller, it fails to write in the log files:

```
package com.mypackage.controller;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

/**
 * @author abhishekkeshri 07/12/2018
 */

@RestController
public class DevController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(DevController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/health")
    public String getCurrentDateTime() {

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        LOGGER.info("Info : number is " + dtf.format(now));
        LOGGER.warn("Warning : number is " + dtf.format(now));
        LOGGER.debug("Debug : number is " + dtf.format(now));
        LOGGER.error("Error : number is " + dtf.format(now));
        LOGGER.fatal("Fatal : number is " + dtf.format(now));
        return(dtf.format(now));
    }

}
```

I have various solutions proposed over different google searches but to no avail, so thought of posting it as a question. What am I doing wrong here?

My project structure is:

```
doc-reader > src > main > java > com.mypackage > controller > DevController
doc-reader > src > main > java > com.mypackage > startup > DRStartupCacheLoader
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven or gradle build tool, you can use dependency:

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api
```

After adding this, can you try with this ?

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DevController.class);

Comment: I solved this, the issue was something else. My dependencies were correct.